# Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of ... when importing a directory with many files

Tags: import, recursion, iteration

I'm doing this:

`Import["/Volumes/Transcend2/images/", "*.jpg"];`

And getting these errors:

[image]

Then, after it's done, when I type "images" and shift+enter, I just get that variable name back.

This folder contains 1.73 GB of images. No subdirectories.

I am now trying ReleaseHold surrounding import.

Comment: What happens if you import a single image?

Comment: When you read in compressed images, Mathematica expands them. Your 1.7 GB of .jpgs likely will overwhelm your memory when expanded.

Comment: When I import a single image, it works without any problems. 

@bills yes it seems when I do it my computer gets a lot slower. Is there anyway to read them compressed? I'm trying to do: FeatureNearest[folderofimages] and then use images not in the data to find the nearest images.

Comment: I would read them in one by one and extract the features, saving only the features. So something like Table[FeatureNearest[Import[ ]],{i,1,number of images}]. The point is you don't need to have all the images in memory at once (only the extracted features).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that